# bootstrap modal not active

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used a boostrap modal snippet for a website of mine. However when i click on it, the whole page is greyed out and the model form is inactive.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

here is the site, please click on the buttom at the bottom of the page:

http://www.playersleague.co.uk/kids/?page=Home

here is the code used to create the modal:https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/squarespace-like-modal

Comment: For some reason, the z-index on `modal-backdrop` is higher than `modal-dialog`. set the second one to 1041

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Added the z index and set it to 1041 worked:

<div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 1041;">

Answer (score 4):

Setting your `.modal-backdrop` z-index value to `0` or `-1` should fix the issue.

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: bootstrap have listed their z-indexes values, maybe `0` or `-1` is a bit too drastic: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#z-index

Comment: Thanks thebrownkid for your answer.

I added the z index and set it to 1041, which worked: 

<div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 1041;">